# How to code a Web Part in C#?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, visual-studio-2013

I use this code to have only the word "quatre" in my listbox of my Web Part but it's not working. Can someone explain why and give me a solution for this problem?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.Windows;

namespace SharePointProject2.accueil
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class accueil : WebPart
    {
        public accueil()
        {
            ListBox1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("quatre");
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
            ListBox1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("quatre");
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("quatre");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this

```
ListBox1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox();
```

You obviously already have the Listbox added in your .ascx. No need to create a new object. Just remove these lines.